# @ViewScoped, f:setPropertyActionListener only works once

Tags: jsf

I have 2 managedBeans: the first one (RequestScoped) sends a parameter to the second one (ViewScoped) through a h:commandLink. Both managedBeans are in the same page, but I use them in different tabs from a rich:TabPanel:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class TheRequestScopedManagedBean {

   private String number
   ...

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class TheViewScopedManagedBean {

    private String number;
    ...
```

And here's the view, wich uses a rich:dataTable:
(The action method is only for showing the second tab from a rich:tabPanel).

```
// ... another dataTable's columns 
<rich:column>
    <f:facet name="header">Number</f:facet>
    <b>
        <a4j:commandLink value="#{theRequestScopedManagedBean.number}"  
         render="someRichPanel" action="#{anotherBean.showSecondTab}" immediate="true">
             <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{theViewScopedManagedBean.number}" value="#{theRequestScopedManagedBean.number}" />
        </a4j:commandLink>
   </b>
</rich:column>
```

The problem here is that theViewScopedBean shows the value only the first time, and when I try to pass it again, it shows its default value (null).

I've seen several questions on this website. But I really don't know what to do in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action="#{anotherBean.showSecondTab}"` is going to result in a navigation case firing. This will in turn result in the views and request scoped beans being destroyed and recreated (as is the expected behaviour for a view scoped bean).

If you're using EL2.2, you could easily just pass the value directly into a method in the view scoped bean. Let's assume your viewscoped bean has a method `takeValue`, you can pass the parameter directly into the method as in:

```
    <a4j:commandLink value="#{theRequestScopedManagedBean.number}" render="someRichPanel" action="#{theViewScopedBean.takeValue(theRequestScopedManagedBean.number)}" immediate="true"/>
```

There are still cleaner ways to transmit data between pages.

- [Communication in JSF2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)

Comment: Due to the fact that you removed the action attribute, I just have another question: how can I switch the next tab if the rich:tabPanel has the "activeItem" attribute?

Comment: @Christian the tab has a `switchToItem(tabname)` javascript function that you can use to switch to a named tab